# How to change mode from User mode to System mode for LockerService

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

In My Org LockerService is enabled automatically and DOM elements are not loading as loading before summer 16 release. Only first component is loading in DOM.

If anyone faced same issue please help me. 
Which structure should I follow for DOM to work with LockerService in User Mode?

Answer (score 1):

> How to change mode from User mode to System mode for LockerService

When LockerService is enabled all your custom components will operate in user mode. The only way to have your components run in system mode is to disable LockerService.

To disable LockerService you'll need to disable the Critical Update (CRUC). If the CRUC isn't present in your org, you can create a new Developer Edition org that will allow you to toggle the CRUC to test your components with and without LockerService. See the "Activate the Critical Update" section of the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_lightning_locker.htm).

> Which structure should I follow for DOM to work with LockerService in User Mode?

With LockerService on, your components can only access DOM elements that they created. As a starting point I recommend running the [Lightning CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_rules.htm) to lint your app and catch any obvious issues.

Answer (score 0):

Shilpa we need more info on what the issue is you are encountering "Only first component is loading in the DOM". Your access to DOM elements you did not create is all that should be filtered but the components themselves should still render and work correctly. Are you creating these dynamically using $A.createComponent() and then component.set("v.body") or similar pattern? Have you opened a support case - if yes please provide the case ID here, if not please open one ASAP with detailed repro info. It sounds like you are hitting a known bug in LS (fix is already set to deploy this coming Tuesday) but I want to be sure it's the same issue. Regardless we will get this fixed so you can reactivate it and keep moving toward LS compliance.